# interpretation of model coefficient in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, regression-coefficients

In simple logistic regression, a common interpretation of the model coefficient $\beta$ is that a 'one-unit increase in the independent variable is associated with an increase of the log-odds ratio of the outcome variable by $\beta$'). This is already answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198428/regression-coefficient-interpretation-in-binary-logistic-regression).

What confused me is that the logit function is not linear with respect to $x$, so how can a one-unit increase in $x$ lead to a constant change in the log-odds ratio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In logistic regression we have that:

$$
\ln\left({\frac{p}{1-p}}\right) = \mathbf{Xb}
$$

where $\mathbf{Xb}$ is the linear predictor, $\mathbf{X}$ being the model matrix of explanatory variables and $\mathbf{b}$ the vector of coefficients.  $\ln\left({\frac{p}{1-p}}\right)$ is the logit function (log of the odds).

Therefore every component of $\mathbf{X}$ (eg, an individual explanatory variable) is proportional to the log odds and so any change in one of them has a linear effect on it.